# make a header full width for browsers

Tags: html, css

I have attached my design also to try and explain things

[image]

Pretty much I want the header to work like a full screen image (example: http://www.flemingsteele.com/) but I thought about cutting the header where the white line is on my design and have it stretch so it will fit all monitor widths. I also want the header fixed.

I want the same to happen with my footer which is just a frosted or low opacity white bar which I want to repeat along the bottom of the page but I want it fixed to the bottom.

The middle part I was thinking of having it as a background colour and have divs inside that area. The problem I have at the moment is whenever I add more information to either div1 or div2 it wont scroll down because ive used position:fixed . the reason for this is I want the divs to stay below the header and when I scroll down the text goes overtop of the header

I also want it so if i add more information into either of the divs and scoll down I want have the header fixed to the top of the browser and when I scroll down all i'll see is the green coloured background, each div with the information and the fixed footer at the bottom.

Heres the coding I have at the moment.

HTML:

```
    <body>
  <img alt="full screen background image" src="images/header.png" id="full-screen-background-image" /> 
<div id="wrapper">

    <div class="logo"><img src="images/bni_logo.png" width="200" height="128" alt="BNI Logo" border="0" /></div>

            <div class="minicontainer">

    <div class="title"></div> 

    <div id="content">
    <P>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. </P>
    <p>It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged.
</div>    
</div><!--MINI CONTAINER DIV!-->
 </div><!--WRAPPER DIV!-->
```

CSS:

```
 #wrapper                       {width:800px; height:auto; margin:0 auto}

.logo                           {margin-left:100px; margin-top:20px; background-image:url(images/bni_logo.png); background-repeat: no-repeat; width:auto; height:auto;}
#header{
    width:100%; 
    background: url(yourimage);
}

.minicontainer                  {padding-left:130px; margin-top:150px; width:800px; height:auto; position:fixed;}

.title                          {background-image:url(images/title.png); width:255px; height:51px;}

#content                        {width:300px; height:auto; padding-left:5px; font-family:Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:12px; line-height:130%;}

/* BACKGROUND IMAGE DO NOT TOUCH */


html, body {
  height: 0%;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  background-color:#8cc643
}

#full-screen-background-image {
  z-index: -999;
  min-height: 30%;
  min-width: 1024px;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```

Hope this is explained clearly enough

Answer (score 0, accepted):

heres the finished product

thank you heaps to everyone that helped.

http://colmandesigns.123abc.co.nz/dev/bni/

Answer (score 2):

As for as my understanding this is what you are trying to do, make the header part and footer part to be fixed. The following code does that.

HTML

```
<div class="header">
</div>

<div class="footer">
</div>
```

CSS

```
.header{width:100%}

.footer {
    background-color: black;
    bottom: 0;
    float: right;
    height: 30px;
    left: 0;
    margin-top: auto;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Example as shown below.
http://jsfiddle.net/4k2Zj/

Comment: yes thats what I'm after. but my design is 3000 px long due to the fact I was going to use the whole image as one big background image and code it to fit fullscreen (example shown here - http://paulmason.name/item/full-screen-background-image-pure-css-code)

how would i achieve this so the header is proportinal for most if not all browsers?

Comment: I might have figured it out but using the full screen code on the header and placing the image inside the header divs.

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is what you are looking for. Please tell me if I am mistaken.

CSS

```
* {margin: 0; padding: 0}
#wrapper {
    background-image: url(http://windturbinezone.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/01/windfarm.jpg);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
#content {
    background-color: #8ac841;
    background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(rgb(138, 200, 65)),to(rgb(188, 252, 109)));
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgb(138, 200, 65), rgb(188, 252, 109));
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgb(138, 200, 65), rgb(188, 252, 109));
    background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, rgb(138, 200, 65), rgb(188, 252, 109));
    background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, rgb(138, 200, 65), rgb(188, 252, 109));
    background-image: linear-gradient(top, rgb(138, 200, 65), rgb(188, 252, 109));
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(GradientType=0,StartColorStr='#8ac841', EndColorStr='#bcfc6d');
    width: 100%;
    height: 500px;
}
#footer {
    background: green;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
}
#div1 {
    left: 100px;
    top: 100px;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    position: relative;
    background-color: yellow;
    display: inline-block;
}
#div2 {
    left: 200px;
    top: 100px;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    position: relative;
    background-color: red;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

HTML

```
<div id="wrapper"></div>
<div id="content">
    <div id="div1">Div1</div>
    <div id="div2">Div2</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I believe you are almost there.

I deleted all my code and replace with yours, but the header/wrapper wont show up. nor will the footer show up. 

I believe once thats sorted I'll be sorted haha